# Why does choosing different datatype yield different results?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix

While calculating entries of the matrix, different results are obtained when defined as float and numpy.complex64 respectively. As some of the entries are large numbers (10^15), the difference seems to be large.

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sy
npc=int(2)
k_pnc=[[E1*A1*kl_1*sy.cot(kl_1*l1),-E1*A1*kl_1*sy.csc(kl_1*l1),0],[-E1*A1*kl_1*sy.csc(kl_1*l1),(E1*A1*kl_1*sy.cot(kl_1*l1)+E2*A2*kl_2*sy.cot(kl_2*l2)),-E2*A2*kl_2*sy.csc(kl_2*l2)],[0,-E2*A2*kl_2*sy.csc(kl_2*l2),E2*A2*kl_2*sy.cot(kl_2*l2)]]
KG=np.zeros((2*npc+2,2*npc+2),dtype=np.complex64)
for i in range(0,2*npc,2):
    KG[i:i + 3, i:i + 3] = k_pnc + KG[i:i + 3, i:i + 3]
KG[2*npc:2*npc+2,2*npc:2*npc+2]=KG[2*npc:2*npc+2,2*npc:2*npc+2]+E1*A1*kl_1*np.array([[sy.cot(kl_1*l1),-sy.csc(kl_1*l1)],[-sy.csc(kl_1*l1),sy.cot(kl_1*l1)]])
KG[-1,-1]=KG[-1,-1]+ sy.I*E1*A1*kl_1
```

`KG`, `Es`, `As` `kl_s` are parameters.

The matrix needed an element at the end which is a complex number. As I started to get unnatural results I removed the complex number added to the last element, `KG[-1,-1]` and compared against `dtype=float`, which gave me different results.

When checked the `KG` matrix possesses different values in each operation even though the calculations are the same.

Why does choosing different datatype yield different results?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Properly formatting your code and variables is very important as it helps us understand the question more quickly. Without formatting you drive away potential help because it takes longer to decipher what you're asking, which isn't your goal I'm sure. SO has help for formatting... "[How do I format my posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)".

Comment: What happens if you use `complex128`?